# Проектирование интерфейса в Android

Tags: android, проектирование, gui

**Доброго времени суток!**

Проектирование интерфейса приложения - дело очень ответственное, ведь именно интерфейс оставляет первое, и, возможно, общее впечатление о приложении. В IntelliJ IDEA, например, весь интерфейс проектируется в обычном XML файле, поэтому я ищу средства, облегчающие проектирование. Я обратил особое внимание на такие способы создания интерфейса, как HTML5 и обычное визуальное проектирование в каком-либо встроенном в IDE редакторе. Последнее наиболее предпочтительнее, но таковых IDE я не нашел( в смысле бесплатных ), поэтому остается лишь HTML5. Но как и главное где можно проектировать интерфейсы таким способом? Как вы проектируете интерфейсы для своих Android-приложений?

**Спасибо.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. IntelliJ IDEA 12 - там уже есть
2. Eclipse - там всегда был можно
3. скачать программку-редактор отдельно

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 12 Community Edition - там нет.

Comment: я с специально качал с рутрекера и ставил, что бы посмотреть - был, работал, достаточно удобный, но после эклипса непривычный

Answer (score 2):

В проектировании интерфейса я все таки сторонник хардкора, но не оголтелого, а разумного:

1. Интерфейс рисуется дизайнером неважно на чем (встречал дизайнеров, которые любят клеить бумажки, куски ткани на листе ватмана).
2. Далее прогер, кодер берет большой кынжал в виде XML и переносит "полет мысли" дизайнера в layout (бесперерывно матерясь и костеря инопланетян дизайнеров). В layout'е остаются "дырки" в виде всяких разных drawable, которые в творческом раже натворил в голове дизайнер (но не создал в виде PNG)
3. Далее берется дизайнер (часто уже другой), которому вменяется задача нарисовать большой (1000*1000 или еще лучше вектора) drawable. Здесь в дело вступает Photoshop или Coreldraw
4. Прогер теперь уже переносит масштабирует как надо созданные drawable в свой layout
5. Далее в зависимости от результатов идет итерация шагов №1-2-3-4

В частном случае и дизайнер и кодер одно и то же лицо, что никак не отменяет общий алгоритм.